# Render SVG in C# Windows RT metro app

Tags: c#, svg, windows-runtime

Is there a way to render a string (containing SVG) to PNG using Windows RT? I know there are libraries like [this](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG), but they rely on GDI+ and it seems too much work changing all those dependencies to e. g. the WritableBitmapEx. I don't need a clean solution and I'd be happy with rendering a browser control displying the SVG, but I don't know if that's possible either.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [SharpVectors](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127039/SharpVectors-SVG-Reloaded-An-Introduction). You can feed SVG string in `FileSvgConverter` which can convert SVG file to corresponding XAML; which then can be rendered on screen. According to documentation there is no GDI+ dependencies.